# Using a variable and a set value inside the convert.ToDateTime function

Tags: vb.net

I have created a program using Visual Basic that when the user enters all values needed and a button clicked, the program links to outlook and sets a reminder with the information previously enterd. I have created a successful program in doing so however the time set for the reminder is 12:00 AM as I have used a Date time picker with a short date(no time).

My question is can I user "convert.ToDateTime(VariableForDate, 8:00 AM) with the second paramater being a set value

current code(Does not work)

```
tmpapp.Start = Convert.ToDateTime(sFollowUpDate, 8:00 AM)

    tmpapp.End = Convert.ToDateTime(sFollowUpDate, 8:00 AM)
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help

Comment: Is this vb.net or outlook-vba? It can't be both.

Comment: ToDateTime accepts only one parameter. But you can change the time afterwards `tmpapp.Start = Convert.ToDateTime(sFollowUpDate)
tmpapp.Start  = tmpapp.Start.AddHours(8)`

Comment: @Blackwood I think it is Vb.NET based on `Convert.ToDateTime`, but yeah, use the right tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only ever have to add hours to a date you can use the AddHours method:

```
tmpapp.start = Convert.ToDateTime(sFollowUpDate).AddHours(8)
```

If you need to add more complex times (hours, minutes and seconds) you can use:

```
tmpapp.start = Convert.ToDateTime(sFollowUpDate).Add(new TimeSpan(8,0,0))
```

The [TimeSpan constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk8a3558%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I've used has arguments for hour, minute and second respectively.

Comment: I think you mean "hours, minutes and seconds" rather than "hour, **day** and minute"